# Ошибка выполнения скрипта

Tags: php, yii

Утро началось с того, что не работает простой код:

```
    $html ="";
    $html.= Chtml::openTag("li");
```

Скрипт просто прекращает работу в этом месте, даже не заходя в код функции `openTag`. В логах пусто, исключения не выкидываются. Кто-нибудь сталкивался?

Весь код:

```
private function f1(Region $region)
{
    $tree ="";
    $tree.= Chtml::openTag("li");
    $tree.= $region->region_name;

    $childrens = $region->children()->findAll();
    if (count($childrens) > 0 && $region->haveObjects == TRUE)
    {
        $tree.= Chtml::openTag("ul", array('style' => 'display:none'));
        foreach ($childrens as $child)
        {
            $this->f1($child);
        }
        $this->obj($region, $tree);
        $tree.= CHtml::closeTag("ul");
    }
    $tree.= CHtml::closeTag("li");
    return $tree;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Таки нашёл решение.
Добавил перед и после вызова моей функции:

```
$html  = CHtml::openTag('ul');
$html .= $this->f1($region);
$tree .= CHtml::closeTag('ul');
```

Заработало

Answer (score 0):

```
$tree=CHtml::encode(CHtml::openTag("li"));
```

ну и т.д.

Значит

```
$tree=CHtml::decode(CHtml::openTag("li"));
   $tree .="<ul>asdf</ul>";
   $tree .=CHtml::decode(CHtml::closeTag("li"));
   echo $tree;
```

и все гуд в функции будет

Comment: Вообще-то encode преобразовывает спецсимвол(например <,>) в сущности. Так что вывод получился  

    <li>Российская Федерация

Comment: @Shrek объясните мне зачем decode? Он тут вообще не к месту.  
openTag и так возвращает нормальные теги(судя по коду самого метода).  
Проблема была в том openTag просто не выполнялся. Как мне кажется это какой-то механизм, для валидации генерируемого html.